# How can I know if indexing a timestamp field on a collection of documents is going to cause problems?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I saw on the Firestore documentation that it is a bad idea to index monotonically increasing values, that it will increase latency. In my app I want to query posts based on unix time which is a double and that is a number that will increase as time moves on, but in my case not perfectly monotonically because people will not be posting every second, in addition I don't think my app will exceed 4 million users. does anyone with expertise think this will be a problem for me

Answer (score 1):

It should be no problem. Just make sure to store it as number and not as String. Othervise the sorting would not work as expected.

Comment: This is a bad idea.  Storing unix timestamps as strings runs the risk of destroying the sort order of those timestamps, since they are not all guaranteed to have the same number of digits.  Strings always sort lexicographically, not numerically.

Comment: I did not say to store them as strings.

Comment: so you think Tarik that I should go for it? someone below you says it would be a bad idea, but my app is for a niche audience not for 100 million people

Comment: also if you had done this before in firestore what was your experience with it

Comment: You wrote there 4 milion users. That is not a small amount but if @DougStevenson can't tell a real alternative I'm not sure what else you could use. Such edge cases are hard to predict. Maybe a realtime database keys won't have such a behaviour. They are sorted by time but are no incremental values. Just generate a key and use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the problem that the Firestore documentation is warning you about.  Your database code will incur a cost of "[hotspotting](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#hotspots)" on the index for the timestamp at scale.  Specifically, from that linked documentation:

> Creates new documents with a monotonically increasing field, like a timestamp, at a very high rate.

The numbers don't have to be purely monotonic.  The hotspotting happens on ranges that are used for sharding the index.  The documentation just doesn't tell you what to expect for those ranges, as they can change over time as the index gains more documents.

Also from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#indexing_best_practices):

> If you index a field that increases or decreases sequentially between documents in a collection, like a timestamp, then the maximum write rate to the collection is **500 writes per second**. If you don't query based on the field with sequential values, you can exempt the field from indexing to bypass this limit.
>
> In an IoT use case with a high write rate, for example, a collection containing documents with a timestamp field might approach the 500 writes per second limit.

If you don't have a situation where new documents are being added rapidly, it's not a near-term problem.  But you should be aware that it just doesn't not scale up like reads and queries will scale against that index.  Note that number of concurrent users is not the issue at all - it's the number of documents being added per second to an index shard, regardless of how many people are causing the behavior.

Comment: What would be a good alternative? He could store the timestamp on another field if he needs the exact data but what would be a good alternative value for such a sorting query?

Comment: what would you recommend for posts to be sorted by time posted?

Comment: also I don't think users will post more than 500 times a second, I'm thinking maybe at its peak 200

Comment: If you're comfortable with the limit, then don't worry about it.  But you should know that the limit exists, because it will start breaking your app at scale.